# VisualLineElementGenerator VerticalAlignment to Center

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

In my application I'm using the TextEditor from Avalon.

With the following code I'm creating a `VisualLineElementGenerator` which works  just fine:

```
internal class SoftwareDependencyElementGenerator : VisualLineElementGenerator
{
    private static readonly Regex imageRegex = new Regex(@"<Dependencies>([ \t])*$");

    private readonly Action<object> doImportAction;

    public SoftwareDependencyElementGenerator(Action<object> doImportAction)
    {
        this.doImportAction = doImportAction;
    }

    private Match FindMatch(int startOffset)
    {
        int endOffset = CurrentContext.VisualLine.LastDocumentLine.EndOffset;
        TextDocument document = CurrentContext.Document;
        string relevantText = document.GetText(startOffset, endOffset - startOffset);
        return imageRegex.Match(relevantText);
    }

    public override int GetFirstInterestedOffset(int startOffset)
    {
        Match match = FindMatch(startOffset);
        return match.Success ? (startOffset + match.Index) : -1;
    }

    public override VisualLineElement ConstructElement(int offset)
    {
        Match match = FindMatch(offset);
        if (match.Success && match.Index == 0)
        {
            return new InlineObjectElement(0, new AddSoftwareDependencyScriptControl(doImportAction));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The AddSoftwareDependencyScriptControl which is created in the ConstructElement method looks like:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApplication.AddSoftwareDependencyScriptControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             Width="16" Height="16" >
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="btn" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Command="{Binding ShowSoftwareDependenciesCommand}" Width="16" Height="16">
            <Button.Content>
                <Grid>
                    <Image Width="14" Height="14" Cursor="Hand" ToolTip="Softwareabhängigkeit hinzufügen"
                           Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources;component/Graphics/Dependency.png"/>
                </Grid>
            </Button.Content>
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

To add the SoftwareDependencyElementGererator to the Avalon-TextEditor I just use:

```
SoftwareDependencyElementGenerator softwareDependencyElementGenerator = new SoftwareDependencyElementGenerator(SelectSoftwareDependency);
AvalonTextEditor.TextArea.TextView.ElementGenerators.Add(softwareDependencyElementGenerator);
```

Everything just works like expected. But the location of the Control is not where I want it to be.

[image]

As you can see. The control is not in the vertical center. I just tried setting the VerticalAlignment of the UserControl, the Button and the Image. Nothing worked. Also making the Image smaller doesn't affect the vertical position.

What can I do to set the Control centered, so it's exactly in one line with the text behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself.

I always tried changing the Margin at the top like 
`Margin="0,10,0,0"` but the solution is to make the margin at the bottom negative.

My solution now is:
`Margin="0,0,0,-18"`